# Player collision with tiles not working, instead falling through them

Tags: python, pygame, collision

Basically I'm learning pygame. and I'm learning from a tutorial, I'm not doing 100% the same but mostly, now I can't figure out why the tutorial works and mine doesn't, in terms of colliding with tiles. Here's my code:

```
import sys

import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # initiate clock
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()  # initiate pygame


WINDOW = (600, 400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW, 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("window")  # set window name
display = pygame.Surface(
    (300, 200)
)  # create display surface, basically makes another image, since all images are surfaces.. kinda
# you can render one surface onto anoher surface


player_image = pygame.image.load(
    "images\me1ns.png"
).convert_alpha()  # load player image, degine player image as variable
player_y_momentum = 0

grass_image = pygame.image.load("images\grass.png").convert()
dirt_image = pygame.image.load("images\dirt.png").convert()
game_map = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]
TILE_SIZE = 16  # size of each tile


def collsion_test(rect, tiles):
    hit_col = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_col.append(tile)
        return hit_col
    # tile collision test, returns a list of tiles that collided with the rect


def move(
    rect, movement, tiles
):  # thing that's being moved, how it's moved, and what tiles it's colliding with
    rect.x += movement[0]  # move on the x axis
    collsions = collsion_test(
        rect, tiles
    )  # returns a list of tiles that collided with the rect
    for tile in collsions:
        if movement[0] > 0:
            rect.right = tile.left
        elif movement[0] < 0:
            rect.left = tile.right
        # if if right, place on left, if left palce on right
    rect.y += movement[1]  # move on the x axis
    collsions = collsion_test(
        rect, tiles
    )  # returns a list of tiles that collided with the rect
    for tile in collsions:
        if movement[1] > 0:
            rect.bottom = tile.top
        elif movement[1] < 0:
            rect.top = tile.bottom
        # if up place on bottom and vice versa
    return rect


# colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
LBLUE = (146, 244, 255)

moving_right = False
moving_left = False
player_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, player_image.get_width(), player_image.get_height())
# getting the player rect(collision), x,y,w,h
# when defining a rect, use pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h), not use pygame.rect(x,y,w,h)
while True:
    display.fill(LBLUE)  # fills screen with color, put images after this
    tile_rects = []
    y = 0
    for row in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in row:
            if tile == 2:
                display.blit(grass_image, (x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE))
            if tile == 1:
                display.blit(dirt_image, (x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE))
            if tile != 0:
                tile_rects.append(
                    pygame.Rect(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)
                )
            x += 1
        y += 1
    # displays tile map, x and y are the location of the tile. We blit based on what the number is, tile is the individual number in map
    # multiple by tile size to get true full size.
    # we make a list of all the tiles in the map, then make a rect for each tile, base on the position of the tile, and ofc TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE

    # update player collision location
    # colliderect checks if someting is collidign with something else

    # movement
    player_movement = [0, 0]
    if moving_right:
        player_movement[0] += 2
    if moving_left:
        player_movement[0] -= 2
    player_movement[1] += player_y_momentum
    player_y_momentum += 0.2
    if player_y_momentum > 3:
        player_y_momentum = 3

    player_rect = move(player_rect, player_movement, tile_rects)
    # moves the player, does collision testing, and returns the new rect.

    display.blit(player_image, (player_rect.x, player_rect.y))
    # puts player image on the screen, at specific location
    # by having it so that you make change, and then check, you can hold and still move\

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # main loop for pygame events
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            print(tile_rects)
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:  # loop for key pressed down
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:  # checks if key is pressed up
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False
    # changes the size of one thing to another
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, (600, 400)), (0, 0))
    # what to blit and where
    pygame.display.update()  # updates the screen
    clock.tick(60)  # 60 fps, has game running at 60 fps
```

I expect to not fall through the ground and istead just be on top of it. I think I understand how things work, not 100% though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an "early `return`" statement that you mistakenly put **inside the loop**, so only the first tile is looked at within this loop:

```
def collsion_test(rect, tiles):
    hit_col = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_col.append(tile)
        return hit_col
```

Try changing to this (note the corrected un-indentation of the return statement:

```
def collsion_test(rect, tiles):
    hit_col = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_col.append(tile)
    return hit_col
```

Comment: yeah, it was the indentation. I thought it was all fine, that function was overlooked because I thought it was just fine. I should've thought to check it, seeing how it's the thing telling me what it being collided with lol. Thanks a lot

Comment: super.  As your game matures, you might consider just identifying the "top layer" of the surface for collision detection as an enhancement.  It shouldn't be necessary to look for collisions 2....3....4....9 layers deep.  ;)